# Semantics (Subtyping)

Tags: haskell, grammar, semantics, subtyping

I am trying to bring the following grammar into the Haskell language :

```
data Expr
  = Var String
  | Bool Bool
  | Int Int
  | Float Float
  | BinaryOp Op Expr Expr
  | UnaryOp UnaryOp Expr
  | App Expr Expr
  | If Expr Expr Expr
  | Let String Expr Expr
  | Lambda String Type Expr
  | Record [(String, Expr)]
  | Prj String Expr
  | Pair Expr Expr
  | Fst Expr
  | Snd Expr
  | Inl Type Expr
  | Inr Type Expr
  | Case Expr String Expr String Expr
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data UnaryOp = Negate | Not | Pot | Sqrt deriving (Show, Eq)

data Op
  = ArithOp ArithOp
  | CompOp CompOp
  | LogicalOp LogicalOp
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data ArithOp = Plus | Times | Minus | Div | Mod deriving (Show, Eq)

data CompOp = Eq | Lt | Gt | Leq | Geq deriving (Show, Eq)

data LogicalOp = And | Or deriving (Show, Eq)
```

And roughly speaking I have the evalStep function that does a single evaluation step anxiously:

```
-- Function to perform one evaluation step.
evalStep :: Expr -> Expr
-- Evaluation of integer expressions (Int).
evalStep (Int x) = Int x
-- Evaluation of Boolean expressions (Bool)
evalStep (Bool b) = Bool b
evalStep (Float f) = Float f
-- Evaluation of variable expressions (Var)
evalStep (Var v) = Var v
-- Evaluation of binary expressions
evalStep (BinaryOp op e1 e2) =
    case evalBinaryOp (BinaryOp op (evalStep e1) (evalStep e2)) of
        Just result -> result
        Nothing -> error ("Binary operation cannot be processed" ++ show op ++ show e1 ++ show e2)
-- Evaluation of unary expressions
evalStep (UnaryOp Negate (Int x)) = Int (-x)
evalStep (UnaryOp Not (Bool b)) = Bool (not b)
-- Remaining unary operations...
-- Evaluation of conditional expressions
evalStep (If (Bool True) e2 _) = e2
evalStep (If (Bool False) _ e3) = e3
evalStep (If e1 e2 e3) =
    let e1' = evalStep e1
     in If e1' e2 e3
-- Evaluation of let expressions
evalStep (Let var e1 e2) = substituteVar var e1 e2
evalStep (App (Lambda argName argType body) argExpr) = substituteVar argName argExpr body
-- Evaluation of lambda expressions (Lambda)
evalStep (Lambda argName argName argType body) = Lambda argName argType (evalStep body)
evalStep (Fst e) = case evalStep e of
    Pair fst _ -> evalStep fst
    _ -> error "Expected a Pair in Fst"
evalStep (Snd e) = case evalStep e of
    Pair _ snd -> evalStep snd
    _ -> error "Expected a Pair in Snd"
evalStep (Pair e1 e2) = Pair (evalStep e1) (evalStep e2)
-- Rest of the cases of expressions according to the grammar
evalStep expr = error ("NO pull" ++ show expr) -- For expressions that don't have an evaluation step
```

The problem is that with some tests I get to something like `App (Var v) e2` and I don't know if my function is doing something wrong or I should treat that issue separately (in theory it should happen that I always have `App (Lambda v e1 e2) e2'`).

Comment: `App (Lambda ...) ...` is not the only case you need to handle. It's possible to have `App e1 e2` where `e1` will produce a lambda in a few steps.

Comment: "anxiously"? I think you mean 'eagerly' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Eager_evaluation:~:text=is%20also%20called-,eager%20evaluation,-or%20greedy%20evaluation. Well done for getting this far.

Comment: For debugging, if you feel `evalStep` is called with an unexpected expression, it might be useful to print the expression passed to `evalStep`. For that you can `import Debug.Trace` and then add the line `evalStep e | traceShow e False = undefined` as the first equation.

Comment: Please add a title that summarizes your specific question, *"Semantics (Subtyping)"* is way to vague. Also it's recommendet to not add tags to the title, which would leave only "()" as the title, even more ambiguous.

Comment: Why should it in theory only happen that you have the form `App (Lambda ...) e`? If `Let` can't define a function, how do you define functions?

Comment: @AntC You are right, it is 'Eagerly,' sorry.

Comment: @molbdnilo You're right, the 'App' function was defined as '(' E E ')', which are like two expressions.

Comment: @chi How could that case be handled? I tried having e1 analyzed first until it becomes a lambda, and then move on to e2, but it goes into an infinite loop there.

Comment: Without more details it's hard to answer. For this kind of small-step semantics I typically use `evalStep :: Expr -> Maybe Expr` where the result `Just e` means that the argument made a single step and became `e`, while `Nothing` means that no step can be taken (we reached a normal form). Using this one can code stuff like: take `e1+e2`, try evaluating `e1`, if it makes a step return `e1' + e2`, otherwise try evaluating `e2`, it it makes a step return `e1 + e2'`, otherwise we have a normal form (e.g. variable+variable).

Comment: If instead `Expr -> Expr` can not be changed, perhaps you need an auxiliary `normalForm :: Expr -> Bool` to detect if something can make a step or not.

Comment: I would expect that adding `evalStep (App e1 e2) = evalStep (App (evalStep e1) e2)` could work.

Comment: @molbdnilo Well, you would need to handle all the primitive `e1` values as errors, of course.